# django: reading from database after form submission

Tags: django, database, forms, django-models, django-views

I have a form in django template that call a javascript function when it's submitted:

```
<input name="button2" type="submit" class="test" id="button2" value="submit"
       onclick="checkSubmitStatus();"/>
```

After form submission, some code in python views, write the data in this form to database. like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    customer_data = Customers(CustomerID=1, CustomerName=request.POST['textfield1'])
    customer_data.save()
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

And in the javascript function I have used ajax to get some data from server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkSubmitStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "CustomerData",
            type: 'get',
            datatype: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                x = data;
            }
        });
            Alert(x);
    }
```

when CustomerData reads the data from DB:

```
return HttpResponse(Customers.objects.get(CustomerID=1).CustomerName)
```

I expect the CustomerData to deliver modified data (the data I enter in the template form), while it returns the previous data. When I refresh the page I can see the updated data. So I'm sure the form data is written to DB, but the script shows shabby data.

Comment: Which view is doing `return HttpResponse(Customers.objects.get(CustomerID=1).CustomerName)`  ? Who triggers that url ?

Comment: CustomerData (that is called in ajax code) @TheMonk

Comment: Bit confusing: you say the form submit button calls the function `checkSubmitStatus()` you also say the ajax that is there in that js function calls the view that returns `return HttpResponse(Customers.objects.get(CustomerID=1).CustomerName)` ?

Comment: @TheMonk Thanks for your attention. Yes, there are two views. One of them provide the whole information for template. Another one just return one data to be used in ajax section after the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make much sense. Your JS function is called on submit; that is, at the point where the submit button is clicked. But at that point, the data does not exist yet, because you haven't submitted the form; and in any case, any Ajax call is going to be immediately replaced by the submission action anyway, so the callback is never going to be invoked.

I don't understand why you have this mixed form POST / Ajax GET. Either submit the form via Ajax and return the updated data in that call; or, submit the form normally, and return the updated data in the standard HTML response from the submission.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. The form is not submitted yet and I don't know how to force the form to be submitted before that call. @daniel-roseman

Comment: Which is why I said not to do it like that. Either submit the whole thing via Ajax and get the data back in that same call, *or* submit the whole thing via standard HTML form and get the data back in the full page response.

Comment: Do you mean that there isn't any way to submit the form in django template and then call a function after form submission? @daniel-roseman